# Difference between byte and char in C

Tags: c

I am wondering why I can't compile an example from book. I simplify the example here to avoid posting example from a copyrighted book.

```
#include <stdio.h>

BYTE *data = "data";

int main()
{
     printf("%s", data);
     return 0;
}
```

When compile with g++, i get error,

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'BYTE*'
```

The program works by simply replacing BYTE with char, but I must be doing something wrong since the example comes from a book.

Please help pointing out the problem. Thanks.

Comment: The question is tagged `C`, but you say that you are using `g++` which is a `C++` compiler. Which language are you using?

Comment: I'm using the C part of C++ . Isnt C++ backward compatible with C, so if I'm only using the C part, it doesn't matter g++ or gcc?

Comment: C++ isn't a quite a superset of C(a few things are missing). However, it doesn't matter for this question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`BYTE` isn't a part of the C language or C standard library so it is totally system dependent on whether it is defined after including just the standard `stdio.h` header file.

On many systems that do define a `BYTE` macro, it is often an `unsigned char`. Converting from a `const char*` to an `unsigned char*` would require an explicit cast.

Comment: Yep - there's your answer idazwaika - custom datatype definitions can cause trouble.

Comment: You may also want to note that the C standard allows the compiler to make char to be either signed char or unsigned char which can lead to some unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I have to hunt for the definition of BYTE macro. Is there a  way I can get the output of C pre-processor where macros are translated already?

Comment: idazuwaika: Use gcc -E (Preprocess only; do not compile, assemble or link)