# How many 'char' types are there in C?

Tags: c

I have been reading "The C Programming Language" book by "KnR", and i've come across this statement:
**"plain chars are signed or unsigned"**

1. So my question is, what is a plain char and how is it any different from
   signed char and unsigned char?
2. In the below code how is 'myPlainChar' - 'A' different from
   'mySignChar' - 'A' and 'myUnsignChar' - 'A'?
3. Can someone please explain me the statement "**Printable char's are
   always positive".**

**Note: Please write examples and explain. Thank you.**

```
{
    char myChar = 'A';
    signed char mySignChar = 'A';
    unsigned char myUnsignChar = 'A';
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to post the third question, as a new question. It is not very related to the first two. If you do, I will retract my close vote.

Comment: Related: [Difference between byte and char in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1592748/1115360).

Comment: [Why is char not compatible with signed char or unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769500/995714)

Comment: "Printable char's are always positive" That's just false, isn't it? If anything, the unprintable ones would be the ones that are always in the positive range in most encodings (because the ISO encodings at least don't add any unprintable characters in addition to the ASCII ones), right?

Answer (score 2):

There are `signed char` and `unsigned char`. Whether `char` is signed or unsigned by default depends on compiler and its settings. Usually it is signed.

Comment: "Usually it is signed" makes it seem like the unsigned variant is unusual, and it depends on how you measure "usually".

Comment: @IanAbbott If it is signed in 90% of cases, this is "usually". GCC + VC for example.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. If you measure it by market share where ARM-based Android phones dominate the operating system market, then "unsigned" wins. So it depends how you measure "usually".

Answer (score 1):

There is only one `char` type, just like there is only one `int` type.

But like with `int` you can add a modifier to tell the compiler if it's an unsigned or a signed `char` (or `int`):

```
signed char   x1;  // x1 can hold values from -128 to +127 (typically)
unsigned char x2;  // x2 can hold values from 0 to +255 (typically)
signed int    y1;  // y1 can hold values from -2147483648 to +2147483647 (typically)
unsigned int  y2;  // y2 can hold values from 0 to +4294967295 (typically)
```

The big difference between plain unmodified `char` and `int` is that `int` without a modifier will *always* be signed, but it's implementation defined (i.e. it's up to the compiler) if `char` without a modifier is signed or unsigned:

```
char x3;  // Could be signed, could be unsigned
int  y3;  // Will always be signed
```

Comment: `signed` and `unsigned` can be used on their own, so I don't think it is correct to call them modifiers.

Comment: @IanAbbott `signed` and `unsigned` on their own are really just aliases for `signed int` and `unsigned int` (respectively).

Comment: Not really. Rather, certain legal combinations of `signed`, `unsigned`, `char`, `short`, `int`, and `long` or `long long` produce certain, unqualified integer types, some of which are identical.

Comment: @IanAbbott I had the same idea but hesitated; I know this is about C, not C++, but a simple check in C++ was to overload a function for signed, unsigned and plain char and call with an argument of each. Would it compile? Yes. What did the compiler choose? Each of the respective functions, i.e. even though char is functionally and implementationally identical to one of the signed/unsigned types, the C++ compiler treats it as distinct type and not as an alias. Does C have specific wording for the character type relations? [Oh, the link in a comment to the OP quotes Note 35 in C99.]

Comment: @IanAbbott Check out n.m's answer which clarifies the point: `signed int` is an alias to `int`, but `char` is a type distinct from all others. The test is to assign pointers to the various types to each other.  In C++ there is also ODR with overloaded functions: you cannot have both `f(int)` and f(signed int)` but you can have `f(char)` and `f(signed char)` on my system with signed chars).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I agree completely with n.m.'s answer, and agree that `signed int` is exactly the same type as `int`. The disagreement here is just about terminology. FWIW, the standard refers to `signed` and `unsigned` as *type specifiers* and as *keywords*, nothing else.

Comment: @IanAbbott `int` can differ from `signed int` with bit fields.  In that case `int` may be signed or unsigned.

Comment: @chux Thanks, I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: Discussing `int` does not well answer OP's question about `char`.  `signed int a` and `int b` are the same type of objects.  `signed char d` and  `char e` are different  types of objects - even if `char` is _signed_.

Answer (score 1):

Plain `char` is the type spelled `char` without `signed` or `unsigned` prefix.

Plain `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three distinct *integral* types (yes, character values are (small) integers), even though plain `char` is represented identically to one of the other two. Which one is implementation defined. This is distinct from say `int` : plain `int` is always the same as `signed int`.

There's a subtle point here: if plain `char` is for example signed, then it is a signed type, and we say "plain char is signed on this system", but it's still *not* the same type as `signed char`.

The difference between these two lines

```
signed char mySignChar = 'A';
unsigned char myUnsignChar = 'A';
```

is exactly the same as the difference between these two lines:

```
signed int mySignInt = 42;
unsigned int myUnsignInt = 42;
```

The statement "Printable char's are always positive" means exactly what it says. On some systems some plain char values are negative. On all systems some signed char values are negative. On all systems there is a character of each kind that is exactly zero. But none of those are printable. Unfortunately the statement *is not necessarily correct* (it is correct about all characters in the *basic execution character set*, but not about the *extended execution character set*).

Comment: "but it's still *not* the same type as `signed char`" - in what way (on a "char defaults to signed" system) can the two types be distinguished ?

Comment: @psmears Their run-time behaviour is exactly the same, but for example `char*` and `signed char*` are different pointer types that can only be converted to each other with an explicit cast. So if a function is declared as `int func(const signed char*)`, you cannot call it `func("abc")`, the compiler will complain.

Comment: Ah yes, good point about the pointer conversions, I'd only been thinking about the raw types :)

Comment: Interesting clarification of the difference between character and the other integer types.

Comment: @n.m. i understand everything you said, but what exactly is the fine difference?

Comment: @shaiknisarahmed Suppose you are on a 64-bit system. `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long` will be usually 16, 32 and 64 bit long, so two of the types will have the same length (normally either `int` and `long` will be 32 bit, or `long` and `long long` will be 64 bit). So you have two types which behave exactly the same, have exact same representation, and yet they are different types. Same story here.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int fun(const signed char*);
int main()
{
fun("hello");
}

int fun(const signed char* a)
{
        printf("%s\n",a);
        return 0;
}

->The compiler doesn't complain, and i'm using gcc compiler.

Comment: @shaiknisarahmed Use -Wall.

Answer (score 0):

> How many char types are there in C?

There is one `char` type. There are 3 small character types: `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`. They are collectively called *character types* in C.

`char` has the same range/size/ranking/encoding as `signed char` or `unsigned char`, yet is a distinct type.

---

1. what is a plain char and how is it any different from signed char and unsigned char?

They are 3 different types in C.  A plain char `char` will match the same range/size/ranking/encoding as either `singed char` or `unsigned char`.  In all cases the size is 1.

---

2 .how is `myPlainChar - 'A'` different from `mySignChar - 'A'` and `myUnsignChar - 'A'`?

`myPlainChar - 'A'` will match one of the other two.
Typically `mySignChar` has a value in the range [-128...127] and `myUnsignChar` in the range of [0...255].  So a subtraction of `'A'` (typically a value of 65) will result a different range of potential answers.

---

3. Can someone please explain me the statement "Printable char's are always positive".

Portable C source code characters (the *basic
execution character set*) are positive so printing a source code file only prints characters of non-negative values.

When printing data with `printf("%c", some_character_type)` or `putc(some_character_type)` the value, either positive or negative is converted to an `unsigned char` before printing.  Thus it is a character associated with a non-negative value that is printed.

C has `isprint(int c)` which "tests for any printing character including space".  That function is only valid for values in the `unsigned char` range and the negative `EOF`.  `isprint(EOF)` reports 0.  So only non-negative values pass the `isprint(int c)` test.

C really has no way to print negative values as characters without undergoing a conversion to `unsigned char`.

Comment: if char has the same range as of signed char then i.e -128 - +127 then what is the narrow difference that plain char has from signed char?
-> As size for all the three is same i.e 1 byte, and same encoding too.

Comment: @shaiknisarahmed "if char has the same range as of signed char ... what is the narrow difference that plain char has from signed char?" Both types have the same size (1), same range, rank (_integer conversion rank_) and encoding (2's complement, 1s' complement, sign-magnitude).  In C, 2 distinct types may share the same properties.  The difference is that they remain distinct types.  See `_Generic(a)` for a way to distinguish `a`: is it type `char` or type `signed char`?

Answer (score -3):

I think it means char without 'unsigned' in front of it ie:

```
unsigned char a;
```

as opposed to

```
char a; // signed char
```

So basically a variable is always signed (for integers and char) unless you use the statement 'unsigned'.

That should answer the second question as well.

The third question: Characters that are in the ascii set are defined as unsigned characters, ie the number -60 doesn't represent a character, but 65 does, ie 'A'.

Comment: Partially right, mostly wrong. It's implementation defined if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I suppose one can in context say that the very last half sentence is correct (-60 does not represent an *ASCII* character, true); everything else is wrong.