# Why i cannot use word, byte on struct in PHP FFI? But char, int, short works?

Tags: php, ffi, php-ffi

My code:

```php
public function loadFFI()
{
    FFI::load("C:\phptest\dummy.h");
}
```

dummy.h:

```c
struct ffitest
{
    char test1[16];
    byte test2;
};
```

Error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught FFI\ParserException: Undefined C type "byte" at line 4

Why can I not use `word` or `byte` in this `struct` in PHP FFI? `char`, `int`, and `short` work as expected.

Comment: I think neither byte nor char are valied PHP types, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php

Comment: I think byte is not a php type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no such thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592737/difference-between-byte-and-char-in-c) as a `byte` data type in standard C. Since `char` is already defined as a single byte, you should use that instead. If you want values 0-255 instead of -127 to 127, don't forget to make it an `unsigned char`.